# Using to_csv to generate a txt file without double quoting

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to export pandas dataframe in txt. Some of data contains double quotes and I can't get it done correctly :

Desired output is a txt file of one column with this format

| No Header |
| --- |
| xxxxxxxx BG {"xxxxxx":"xxxx","xxxxx":"xxxxxx"} |
| yyyyyy BG {"yyyy":"yyyyy","yyyy":{"yyyy":""},"yyyy":{"yyyyy": {"yyyy":"yyyy","yyyyy":"yyyy"}},"yyy":"yyy","yyyy":"yyy","yyy":"yyyyyy","yyyy":"yyyyyy"} |

The problem is that to_csv is doubling every `""`, I've already used

```
df.to_csv("df.txt",header=False,index=False,doublequote=False,escapechar=" ")
```

But by using it, the extra quote becomes a space, so I was wondering if there is a way to avoid that.

To put the quotes into the string I've used `'"THIS FORMAT"'`

Comment: That is NOT a CSV.  Why would you even pretend that it is?  It's just a text file.  Is that example showing the exact contents of your dataframe?  Why don't you just iterate through the rows and write it exactly as you want it?

Comment: the df has the correct content but I need to convert that df into a txt file,  and that is why, I'm using to_csv  to create the txt file, do you think if I use another way to create the txt file the problem will be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need complete control over the output, then you have to take control.  You can't use the automated tools.

```
import pandas as pd
       
d = [
    ['xxxxxxxx BG {"xxxxxx":"xxxx","xxxxx":"xxxxxx"}' ],
    ['yyyyyy BG {"yyyy":"yyyyy","yyyy":{"yyyy":""},"yyyy":{"yyyyy": {"yyyy":"yyyy","yyyyy":"yyyy"}},"yyy":"yyy","yyyy":"yyy","yyy":"yyyyyy","yyyy":"yyyyyy"}']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['No Header'])
with open('xxx.txt','w') as out:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        print(row[1].iloc[0], file=out)
```

Comment: Well, a big part of this is pandas, which has its own quirks beyond Python...